# Keras model seems not to load weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

My model is the combination of keras and tensorflow like below:

```
with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
    with tf.device("/device:GPU:0"):


        raw_img_float = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,512,640,3)) #tf.divide(tf.cast(raw_img, tf.float32),tf.constant(255.0))



        bbox_tensor = tf.stack([by1,bx1,by2,bx2],axis=1)

        cropped_img = tf.image.crop_and_resize(image=raw_img_float, # (n, 512, 640, 3)
                                                   boxes=bbox_tensor,# (n,4)
                                                   box_ind=list(range(BATCH)),#[0,1], # (n)
                                                   crop_size=[int(NETWORK_INPUT_SIZE),int(NETWORK_INPUT_SIZE)])

    crop_width = tf.cast(tf.subtract(bx2,bx1), tf.float32)
    new_crop_width = tf.reshape(crop_width, [-1, 1])

    crop_height = tf.cast(tf.subtract(by2,by1), tf.float32)
    new_crop_height = tf.reshape(crop_height, [-1, 1])

    x_coords = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,5))
    y_coords = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,5))

    with tf.device("/device:GPU:1"):
         inception = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False,
                           input_shape=(299,299,3))
         inception_transfer = inception(cropped_img)
         inception_transfer_flatten = Flatten(name='flatten')(inception_transfer)

         inception_do1 = Dropout(0.5)(inception_transfer_flatten)
         inception_regress_x = Dense(5, name='inception_regress_x')(inception_do1)
         inception_regress_y = Dense(5, name='inception_regress_y')(inception_do1)

saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=tf.trainable_variables())
ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state('checkpoint1')

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())


if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
    saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
    print('RESTORED')

....

if global_step.eval(session=sess) % 200 == 0:
     model_path = 
     os.path.join(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'checkpoint1'),'model.ckpt')
            saver.save(sess, model_path, global_step=global_step)
```

I trained the model above and saw the cost going down properly.

But when loading the weights and executing, it shows the result of the model not trained at all...

How could I save the weights of the model defined as Keras API?

Thanks advance...

Comment: is the model getting saved in the path you have mentioned?